# Flutter: Cursor Position Shift to left in TextField after SetState is called

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have a textField in which if there is no value then border color changes to red after the user put value I have called the setState method to change the border color to grey again.

but as soon as the user put a value and setState is called the cursor position shift to the beginning or left, I have tried many approaches to correct it but nothing works.

Code to my textField :-

```
TextField(
              controller: textEditingController,
              onChanged: (text) {
                //print(textEditingController.selection);

                if (text.length == 0) {
                  addbuttonDisable = true;
                  firstTime = true;
                  setState(() {
                    _validate = true;
                    currentIndexCheck = index;
                  });
                }
                if (text.length >= 1) {
                  addbuttonDisable = false;
                }
                if (text.length >= 1 && firstTime) {       <<== this is the condition after which cursor shift to left.
                  setState(() {
                    _validate = false;
                    firstTime = false;
                    });
                  textEditingController.value.copyWith(  <<== approach i have tried to change cursor positon.
                      selection: TextSelection.fromPosition(
                          TextPosition(offset: text.length+2)));

                }
                if (lstOfStrings.length > index) {
                  lstOfStrings.removeAt(index);
                  lstOfStrings.insert(index, text);
                } else {
                  lstOfStrings.add(text);
                }
              },
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                //errorText: _validate? "value can't be null": null,
                border: InputBorder.none,
                contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 2, right: 2, bottom: 2.5),
                isDense: true,
              ),
              maxLines: 1,
            ),
```

if the condition which causes the problem is commented everything works. Please suggest me a solution or if I am doing something wrong here. What is want is that the cursor remains to end of user inputs words.

Answer (score 0):

Since **copyWith** doest set the value of the object

You have to

```dart
textEditingController.value=textEditingController.value.copyWith(  <<== approach i have tried to change cursor positon.
                      selection: TextSelection.fromPosition(
                          TextPosition(offset: text.length+2)));
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is setState(). It repopulates the widget in memory. If your widget is loosely coupled with widget tree. It tends to re-build the widget. Hence, the cursor goes at the start.

So the best way is to store the state of TextField is by using `GlobalKeys`.

```
GlobalKey _orderFormKey = GlobalKey();
Widget someFunction(){
   return TextField(
        key: _orderFormKey,
        ....
}
```

If this doesn't work you could use

```
GlobalKey _orderFormKey = GlobalKey();
Widget someFunction(){
   if(_orderFormKey.currentWidget!=null){
     return _orderFormKey.currentWidget;
   }else{
     return TextField(
        key: _orderFormKey,
        ....
}
```

Use this with precaution as it would not let setState() make any changes to its state through regular methods.